# concat rows in 2nd table of query

Tags: mysql

Have created an sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4bff/8 I think!

I'm running the following query on 2 tables (the second inner joined to the first):

```
SELECT c.name
     , c.custom_message
     , d.log_id
     , c.price
     , c.quantity
     , d.value 
  FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents c
  JOIN wp_wpsc_submited_form_data d
    ON d.log_id = c.purchaseid 
 WHERE c.name LIKE '%$term%' 
 ORDER 
    BY c.name
```

The first table has all the data I need in single rows, but the second table has the data spread over 6 rows in one column. This is resulting in 6 instances of the same data in table 1.
How can I concatinate the data in table 2 to eliminate the repeats?

Screenshot of table 2

[image]

Comment: Hi Strawberry - so, thanks - that amazing clean up of my code works great - but no concat of 2nd table?

Comment: Without seeing proper DDLs, I struggle to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name, wp_wpsc_cart_contents.custom_message,
    wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.log_id, wp_wpsc_cart_contents.price,
    wp_wpsc_cart_contents.quantity, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.value) AS value
FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents 
INNER JOIN wp_wpsc_submited_form_data 
ON wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.log_id=wp_wpsc_cart_contents.purchaseid 
WHERE wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name LIKE '%$term%' 
GROUP BY wp_wpsc_submitted_form_data.log_id
ORDER BY wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4bff/12)

Comment: Makes sense to me and I appreciate your answer.  Unfortunately, it broke the query somehow (white spaces?) and returned an empty table????

Comment: Tried cleaning white spaces as a punt - but query doesn't want to work I'm afraid. Took out GROUP_CONCAT stuff and back to working query - with repeats! More help needed!!

Comment: GROUP BY has to be before ORDER BY. Try it now.

Comment: oh heck! --- dead table! ---SELECT wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name, wp_wpsc_cart_contents.custom_message,
    wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.log_id, wp_wpsc_cart_contents.price,
    wp_wpsc_cart_contents.quantity, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.value) AS new
FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents 
INNER JOIN wp_wpsc_submited_form_data 
ON wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.log_id=wp_wpsc_cart_contents.purchaseid 
WHERE wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name LIKE '%$term%' 
GROUP BY wp_wpsc_form_data.log_id
ORDER BY wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. If the query still isn't working, please make a sqlfiddle with sample data that I can experiment with.

Comment: Hi Barmar. OK - will do - tomorrow. Not done a fiddle before so please bare with me. What I meant was that with that query the query ran ok, but came back with no data

Comment: To Strawberry - DDLs?

Comment: DDL = Data Definition Language, i.e. the schema of your tables. To send a comment to a particular user, put `@` before their name, not `To`.

Comment: OK, thanks Barmar. What's the best way to show my schema? I'm thinking screenshots?

Comment: Not screenshots. Paste the text output of `show create table <tablename>`. You'll need to do this when you create the sqlfiddle.

Comment: Right. Tomorrow's project! Thanks so far.

Comment: Last thing tonight and sorry to pain you with this, but where do I need to go to create a fiddle?

Comment: I had an incorrect table name in the `GROUP BY` clause. I fixed that, and replaced `$term` with some text that matches the names, and the query works.

Comment: Thanks once again. Erm.. where do I go to see your fixed query? Sorry if I'm being slow

Comment: So you did. Brilliant!

Comment: I think that's me sorted. I know we're not supposed to use words like thanks in here - but thanks!  I see that the table name error was the plugin author's fault for not knowing how to spell submitted!

Comment: Actually, I was missing that whole word, I just had `wp_wpsc_form_data`.